# Start() being called 2 times with Photon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I'm making a multiplayer system. I have a strange situation about `Start()`. When the first player joins there is 2 logs "player joined". So, when second player joins, their model instantiates twice (there is `PhotonNetwork.Instantiate` in `Start()`). I guess `Start()` is being called 2 times somehow?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using TMPro;
public class MPRoomServer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject rocket;
    public TMP_Text title;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(rocket.name, new Vector3(20.4928417f,4.3900001f,-10.116004f), Quaternion.identity);
        title.text = "Room " + PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.Name;
        Debug.Log("New player joined");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably have two copies of this script in your scene.  In the scene window's hierarchy search bar, type "t:MPRoomServer" and it'll show you all the objects that have this script on them.  If it shows a single object, you might have two copies of the script on a single object.

Comment: no, i have only one script on scene

Comment: Then you're instantiating another object with this script on it.  `Start()` is only ever called once per-instance.

Answer (score 0):

`OnJoinedRoom()` works even when you create a room. So, my scene was loaded 2 times, and the script was used 2 times.